# Binary sequence and Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, binary, cantor-set

I am not familiar with Cantor set, so I would like to ask suppose I have a Cantor set $C$ which represented in binary sequence. Let $x\in C$ and now I change 1 entry in $x$, will the new sequence in $C$?

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $(1,1,...)$ represents $1$. If you change  the first coordinate to $0$ you get $\frac 1 2$ which is not in $C$.

Comment: Is this property holds for any member in $C$?